# Qt ASCII to IP function

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qtnetwork

I'm attempting my hand at creating a UDP terminal (custom) using Qt - Does anyone know if there's a widget or class for handling the conversion of the IP address from ASCII to numeric (hex) or do I have to write that myself? Basically "192.168.1.1" -> "0xC0A80101". I'm not opposed to writing it, just want to know if anyone knows if it already exists. Tried searching, not much luck. Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key class here is [QHostAddress](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qhostaddress.html) as follows:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QHostAddress>

#include <QTextStream>
#include <QString>

int main()
{
    QTextStream standardOutput(stdout);
    // You could use this, too:
    // standardOutput.setIntegerBase(16);
    // standardOutPut.setNumberFlags(QTextStream::ShowBase);
    quint32 ipAddress = QHostAddress("192.168.1.1").toIPv4Address();
    QString hexIpAddress = QString::number(ipAddress, 16);
    QString prefixedUppercaseHexIpAddress = QString("0x%1")
                                            .arg(uppercaseHexIpAddress);
    standardOutput << prefixedUppercaseHexIpAddress;
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core network
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
0xC0A80101
```

Comment: Laszlo - what is the difference between what you posted, and what Pavel posted? I'm still learning C/C++ as I go - please don't crucify me for this lol. I'm assuming that the 0x%1 refers to making the values uppercase? BAsically I want the program user to enter an IP address, and have it convert to the proper form to use in the outgoing UDP packet. So as in my example, if I look at the converted value, I'll see 0xC0A80101 in my debugger and not the ascii characters... ? Thanks for your patience..

Comment: @JediEngineer: "0x" can be found in your request. That is the marker of the hex value. %1 means that the parameter is supplied later in the .arg() method argument. You could write QString("0x") + ..., too, but I prefer this style since it is more concise.

Comment: @JediEngineer: welcome. I have made it a bit even more comprehensive for you with interim variables to be more talkative.

Comment: I think I asked my question wrong. I should have omitted the quotes around the hex number. I believe the method I was looking for was:

quint32 ipAddress = QHostAddress("192.168.1.1").toIPv4Address();

Thanks though, for all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `QHostAddress` to parse string IP representation and convert it to number. Use `QString::number` to convert number to hex string. See this one-liner:

```
qDebug() << QString::number(QHostAddress("192.168.1.1").toIPv4Address(), 16);
```

Output: `"c0a80101"`

Comment: It has two issues: 1) Missing 0x 2) lowercase as opposed to uppercase.